# How to add Follow Me link inside content type in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

My project contains two content types:- Professor and Lecturer.
Here the users are student so students can log in using their own credentials.

Now I want to show up a button/link with Text "Follow Me" in Professor & Lecturer Content Type.When User/student will select the link/button then the corresponding Lecturer/Professor will be attached to the student profile and will be visible inside their home page. Similarly that student will be visible in Teacher/Lecturer.

I look at The "Relation" Module in Drupal 7 but my use case don't need to display too many things in the widget. There should be a simple button/link which relate user and content type.

Answer (score 4):

You should try the [Flag module](http://drupal.org/project/flag) for this. It should solve your purpose.

> Flag is a flexible flagging system that is completely customizable by the administrator. Using this module, the site administrator can provide any number of flags for nodes, comments, users, and any other type of entity. Some possibilities include bookmarks, marking important, friends, or flag as offensive. With extensive views integration, you can create custom lists of popular content or keep tabs on important content.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Your valuable suggestion make my day.

Comment: @user1843970 don't forget to accept it, by checking the "tick" just below the votes :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar case where I needed to attach students to an instructor's class and have instructors print out class lists of attached users.

I used [node registration](http://drupal.org/project/node_registration) to achieve this effect. And set up the registration parameters during the Content Creation process with node registration set to On by Default.

After, you can make some views with filters to display node registrants as a block and place it wherever you need.

Answer (score -1):

There is [Shortcode](http://drupal.org/project/shortcode) Module also

> Shortcodes are actually macros to be used in the text of contents.
> These macros change the text of the content and format the given part
> through the theme engine.
>
> Shortcode is an API that handles the shortcode macros for text
> formats. You can add your own shortcode tags via this API. All tags
> are themeable and new tags can be provided by other modules.